# Holding reference types in value typed list?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

In this discussion [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/79923/2747431) I learned that value types are kept at the stack and pointers at the heap.In my application I have some `QList<T*>` and `QMap<QString,QList<QString>>` holding Pointers of some Objects.

Now I know, the reference types are holding at the heap (application). But my lists, holding this references, are value types and so they are at the stack. They are only available in the thread in which they were created. But how do I know, when a thread will be dead, or if a function/method, that I call is in another thread? I need the lists in the whole application. Is a bit stupid question but I fill my lists and its a mere chance if the objects are available.

EDIT:

> @coyotte508
>
> The only things in the stack are the member pointers pointing to that
>   memory. And that is, if they were created in the stack, which is only
>   if they're local variables of a function or of another class declared
>   on the stack.

In my main class I have an list: `QList<Fachbereich *> lFBs;`

In constructor of my main class I create the list:

```
lFBs=QList<Fachbereich *> ();
```

..- Then I call the method `ReadConfig();`

One of its subroutines :

```
void AppConfig::ReadFachbereiche(QXmlStreamReader &reader)
{
    Fachbereich* fb(0);
    while(!reader.atEnd())
    {
        reader.readNext();
        if (reader.error())
        {
            bla bla

        }
        else
        {
            if (reader.isStartElement())
            {
                if (reader.name().toString().toLower() == "fb")
                {
                    QString sFB="";

                    try{ sFB=reader.attributes().value("name").toString();}
                    catch(...){}

                    if (sFB !="")
                    {
                        fb=new Fachbereich();
                        fb->Name=sFB;
                    }
                }
                else if (reader.name().toString().toLower() == "stddir")
                {
                    if (fb!=0) fb->stdDir=reader.readElementText().replace("\\", "/").toLower();
                }
            }
            else if (reader.isEndElement())
            {
                if (reader.name().toString().toLower() == "fb")
                {
                    if (fb!=0){
                        if (!lFBs.contains(fb))
                            lFBs.append(fb);
                    }
                }
                else if (reader.name().toString().toLower() == "fachbereiche") return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So `fb` is a local variable of this function. I thought, by creating a object with `new` the memory will be allocated at the heap, but isn't.  The new created, to my listappended reference types are gone, when leaving the function.

Should i store the objects in a `QSharedPointer`?
Sth. like this?

```
QList<QSharedPointer> lFBs;
```

...

```
QSharedPointer<Fachbereich> fb= QSharedPointer<Fachbereich>(new Fachbereich);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't have much to do with threads.

The thing you want is to keep the `fb` variable outside the function.

And you add it to the list, which is good.

```
if (reader.name().toString().toLower() == "fb")
{
    if (fb!=0){
        if (!lFBs.contains(fb))
            lFBs.append(fb);
    }
}
else if (reader.name().toString().toLower() == "fachbereiche") return;
```

But you only do it in some cases, and sometimes (when the name is "fachbereiche") you directly return. I don't think you need to even put it in a pointer. `QList<Fachbereich>` saves data, and since it's a member of your class, the data will be saved until your class is destroyed.

What I would do:

- Stop using pointers or `new`. It depends on how Fachbereich is created, but it shouldn't pose problems
- Make sure the element is always added to the list if needed.

For that, at the beginning of the function:

```
Fachbereich fb;
bool somethingRead = false;
```

When deciding to "create" `fb`, just set the boolean to true:

```
if (sFB !="")
{
    /* Maybe add a debugging message here to say it was created */
    somethingRead = true;
    fb.Name=sFB;
}
```

Replace this code:

```
            if (reader.name().toString().toLower() == "fb")
            {
                if (fb!=0){
                    if (!lFBs.contains(fb))
                        lFBs.append(fb);
                }
            }
            else if (reader.name().toString().toLower() == "fachbereiche") return;
```

by:

```
break; //leave the loop
```

And finally, at the end of the function, after the loop:

```
/* The boolean is true if fb was initialized */
if (somethingRead) {
    lFb.push_back(fb);
}
```

Then after the function was called, `lFb.size()` of your class should be more than 0 and `lFb.last()` should contain your element.

`QList` internally stores the object after allocating them with `new`, so you don't need to worry about that.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving attention to my problem. Think, I used reference types, because I want to know, if the objects are initialized. Now I accept your advise and it works fine :)